# Retrieving ChildItem from ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am trying to retrieve childitem when user clicked on the childitem of ExpandableListView.For that my Activity and ListAdapter classes are as follows..

**MainActivity:-**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    NewAdapter mNewAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ExpandableListView expandbleLis = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
        expandbleLis.setDividerHeight(2);
        expandbleLis.setGroupIndicator(null);
        expandbleLis.setClickable(true);

        setGroupData();
        setChildGroupData();

        mNewAdapter = new NewAdapter(groupItem, childItem);
        mNewAdapter
                .setInflater(
                        (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE),
                        this);
        expandbleLis.setAdapter(mNewAdapter);
        expandbleLis.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "GroupItem Clicked" + groupItem.get(groupPosition),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
        expandbleLis.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ChildItem Clicked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    public void setGroupData() {
        groupItem.add("TechNology");
        groupItem.add("Mobile");
        groupItem.add("Manufacturer");
        groupItem.add("Extras");
    }

    ArrayList<String> groupItem = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Object> childItem = new ArrayList<Object>();

    public void setChildGroupData() {
        /**
         * Add Data For TecthNology
         */
        ArrayList<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Java");
        child.add("Drupal");
        child.add(".Net Framework");
        child.add("PHP");
        childItem.add(child);

        /**
         * Add Data For Mobile
         */
        child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Android");
        child.add("Window Mobile");
        child.add("iPHone");
        child.add("Blackberry");
        childItem.add(child);
        /**
         * Add Data For Manufacture
         */
        child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("HTC");
        child.add("Apple");
        child.add("Samsung");
        child.add("Nokia");
        childItem.add(child);
        /**
         * Add Data For Extras
         */
        child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Contact Us");
        child.add("About Us");
        child.add("Location");
        child.add("Root Cause");
        childItem.add(child);
    }

}
```

**ListAdapter:-**

```
public class NewAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    public ArrayList<String> groupItem, tempChild;
    public ArrayList<Object> Childtem = new ArrayList<Object>();
    public LayoutInflater minflater;
    public Activity activity;

    public NewAdapter(ArrayList<String> grList, ArrayList<Object> childItem) {
        groupItem = grList;
        this.Childtem = childItem;
    }

    public void setInflater(LayoutInflater mInflater, Activity act) {
        this.minflater = mInflater;
        activity = act;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        tempChild = (ArrayList<String>) Childtem.get(groupPosition);
        TextView text = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = minflater.inflate(R.layout.childrow, null);
        }
        text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        text.setText(tempChild.get(childPosition));
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return ((ArrayList<String>) Childtem.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groupItem.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // isExpanded = false;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = minflater.inflate(R.layout.grouprow, null);
        }
        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(groupItem.get(groupPosition));

        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

I have Googled tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884031/like-to-know-how-to-get-selected-item-in-expandable-list-android) but no use i'm not getting child item from it. please help in doing this.

After trying many possible solutions i'm posting this please try to help me don't down vote if you are voting down say possible solution then i'll agree..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple issues:

- The child item needs to be selectable for the click to work. Change your adapter's `isChildSelectable()` to return `true`.
- Remove `android:clickable="true"` from your `childrow.xml` root `LinearLayout`. (Or alternatively, add a click handler to the `LinearLayout` itself.)
- Implement `getGroup()` and `getChild()` to return actual objects instead of `null` and `getGroupId()` and `getChildId()` to return locally unique identifiers. That is, child ids within a group need to be unique but they do not need to be unique across groups. In your case, returning child/group position as an id will do.

Comment: if it is true also not getting retrieved child item.

Comment: Then the problem is not in the code you've posted. It works for me when copy-pasted to my environment and adding the required layout files. What does your `childrow.xml` look like?

Comment: There was another problem there. Added second bullet to my answer.

Comment: now getting performed click but selected item not getting retrieved.

Comment: Not sure what you exactly mean but of course you need to implement `getGroup()` and `getChild()` to return non-`null`objects and `getGroupId()` and `getChildId()` to return (locally) unique identifiers.

Comment: i mean i want to retrieve clicked childitem .

Comment: Thanks Now it is working fine.Now accepting answer,need some more help .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055819/retrieving-childitem-from-expandablelistview?rq=1  @laalto can you help me for this question ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `ListAdapter`,

change `return` value of

`public Object getGroup(int groupPosition)`

and

`getGroupId(int groupPosition)`

to

`return groupPosition;`